# Feedback Form Using Jquery Selects with PHPMailer-FE, the word "Array" is showing up in the results email

Tags: php, jquery, forms, phpmailer, task-parallel-library

I am using PHPMailer-FE to send results of a feedback form via email.  I have configured PHPMailer-FE and am receiving all emails and form results correctly, with one exception.   When I receive the email with my form results, 3 fields are not showing the values.   Instead of being a comma separated list of the values chosen by the user, I get just the word "Array".   For each of these 3 erroneous results, I am using a multiple select (jquery plugin, "jquery.amselect.js").   So, multiple values are being selected by the user, but not displayed in the email results.

PHP Mailer FE works very nicely but doesn't seem to play well with my Amselect.js widget.
I am able to preview the values in a comma separated list before the form is submitted so I know the multiselects are functioning, but somehow the array is not directly shown in the results email.

**These are the PHP files I am using:**
http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Form-Processors/PHPMailer-FE-46189.html

**This is how my Multiselects are setup:** 
[Demo Multiselects Using JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFgnn/)
**Below is an excerpt of my TPL File:**  *(my actual TPL is much larger but follows the same exact pattern)*

***HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED I AM STILL LEARNING BUT HAVE BEEN WORKING AT THIS PROJECT DAY AND NIGHT!***

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="3" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
 <tr>
   <th colspan="2" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;">SIF SUBMISSION RESULTS </th>
 <tr>
 <tr>
   <th align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;">Form Field</th>
   <th align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;">Value</th>
 <tr>
 <tr>
   <td style="border-collapse:collapse;" align="left">Name:</td>
   <td style="border-collapse:collapse;">{firstName}</td>
 <tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="border-collapse:collapse;" align="left">Credit Cards:</td>
   <td style="border-collapse:collapse;">{cards}</td>
 <tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="border-collapse:collapse;" align="left">Gateway Selected:</td>
   <td style="border-collapse:collapse;">{processor}</td>
    <tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: need to see the php code for the email

Comment: I am using PHPMailer-FE which uses several PHP files, a configuration file, and a TPL file to send the email. I had to modify very little this script pretty much works out of the box. It simply reads all form values from the page and puts them in an email. Everything works great except for the multiselects. It must be a simple revision to one of the PHP files however I am still learning PHP and am not clear on what to revise. What would you suggest? I have updated the question to include a download link so you can take a look at the PHP script I am using. Many thanks.

Comment: @Dagon, I really didnt have to write any php.   I simply uploaded the files to my webserver and set the form action to the main class file.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more code. If you saw 'Array', I think you are echoing an array directly, like this:

```
echo $list;
```

instead of

```
echo join(",", $list);
```

to see a comma separated list.

Comment: I am using PHPMailer-FE which uses several PHP files, a configuration file, and a TPL file to send the email.   I had to modify very little this script pretty much works out of the box.   It simply reads all form values from the page and puts them in an email.  Everything works great except for the multiselects.   It must be a simple revision to one of the PHP files however I am still learning PHP and am not clear on what to revise.   What would you suggest?   I have updated the question to include a download link so you can take a look at the PHP script I am using.    Many thanks.